# if statement not working in IE but work in chrome

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, internet-explorer, controller

I'm using codeigniter for web application, below code from Controller. but it pass thru gid>5 but if statement inside are not working only in IE but chrome are work.

```
$totalTime6hrs = '50000'
if ($gid > 5){
    if ($checkTime > 0)
    {
        // Booking not available
        echo '-1';
    }
    else if ($totalTime6hrs > 21600){
        // Separate room booking cannot be exceed 6 hours;
        echo '-2';
    }
    else if ($totalTime4hrs > 14400){
        // Same room booking cannot be exceed 4 hours;
        echo '-3';
    }
```

Comment: PHP runs on your server, not in the browser. It is very unlikely that the browser you use would have any impact on this code. What do you expect it to do? What happens instead?

Comment: Answered on bottom, PHP running on server, not on the client-side that means the error is not from your browser, but from your server, especially from your code.

Comment: Please detail more the error on browsers, on php side does not seems to offer enough information. have you javascript errors or something?

Comment: solved it. it was the error passing datetime data into controller.